# how to filter ngtagsinput autocomplete results on key stroke

Tags: angularjs, filter, autocomplete, ng-tags-input

i am using `ngTagsInput` directive in my `angularjs` app. As `ngtagsinput` autocomplete does not filter any results, i want to get the filtered results from my api through service call and return promise to the autocomplete of `tagsinput` on every key stroke.

In my `angularjs` app i am getting the filtered results from the api on every keystroke but they are not appearing in view i.e., the auto complete results displayed are not updating on keystroke even though i am getting the results from api.

Can anyone help me in achieving this?

Comment: Need some code to understand what you mean in practice

Comment: @beaver  hi beaver thanks for responding , http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/ is the ngtagsinput directive we are using in our angularjs app. lets say we have a array like ['mango','apple','banana']. if we type letter 'a' then the apple should come as first value in autocomplete. As ngtagsinput autocomplete does not filter any results, so i am filtering my results in the backend and sending those results to frontend,

Comment: @beaver but for every key stroke it is going backend and retrieving the results and the autocomplete results displayed are not updating for every key stroke retrieved values instead the autocomplete results are displaying the results retrieved in first key stroke.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a [pen](http://codepen.io/origin1tech/pen/RaQjLa) I found with the answer; basically you use the angular filter:

```
  $scope.loadTags = function(query) {
    return $timeout(function () { 
      return $filter('filter')($scope.allPossibleTags, query);
    });
  };
```